# How to print all activation shapes (more detailed than summary()) for Tensorflow V2 keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I've spent a lot of time with Tensorflow v.0 and v.1, and now I'm trying Tensorflow v.2 keras model. `model.summary()` looked easy and convenient, but lack details.

Here's a toy example. Let's say I define custom layers and models as below (a functional API style and a subclass syle).

Please see below. I wanted to see primitive layers inside the custom layers, but `.summary()` only shows shallow information (only direct children layers).

**Toy custom layers (layers are just toy definitions):**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Dense, Conv2D, BatchNormalization)

class LayerA(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, **kwargs):
        super(LayerA, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.dense1 = Dense(64)
        self.dense2 = Dense(128)
        self.dense3 = Dense(num_outputs)
        self.bn = BatchNormalization(trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
        return x
    
class LayerB(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, **kwargs):
        super(LayerB, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.dense = Dense(64)
        self.bn = BatchNormalization(trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        x = self.dense(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
        return x
```

**Model definition with functional API:**

```py
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28), name='input')
x = LayerA(7, name='layer_a')(inputs)
x = LayerB(13, name='layer_b')(x)
x = tf.reduce_max(x, 1)
model_func = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x, name='model')
model_func.summary()

# Results:
# Layer (type)                 Output Shape              # Param #   
# =================================================================
# input (InputLayer)           [(None, 28)]              0         
# _________________________________________________________________
# layer_a (LayerA)             (None, 64)                2112      
# layer_b (LayerB)             (None, 64)                4416      
# tf_op_layer_Max_1 (TensorFlo [(None,)]                 0         
# =================================================================
# Total params: 6,528
# Trainable params: 6,272
# Non-trainable params: 256
```

**Model definition subclassing:**

```py
class ModelA(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelA, self).__init__()
        self.block_1 = LayerA(7, name='layer_a')
        self.block_2 = LayerB(13, name='layer_b')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.block_1(inputs)
        x = self.block_2(x)
        x = tf.reduce_max(x, 1)
        return x

model_subclass = ModelA()
y = model_subclass(inputs)
model_subclass.summary()

### Result:
# Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
# =================================================================
# layer_a (LayerA)             (None, 64)                2112      
# layer_b (LayerB)             (None, 64)                4416      
# =================================================================
# Total params: 6,528
# Trainable params: 6,016
# Non-trainable params: 512
```

How can I prints all the activation shapes of `Conv` and `Dense` layers in the model? For example,

```
layer_a/dense_1                          (None, ...)
layer_a/dense_2                          (None, ...)
layer_b/dense_1                          (None, ...)
layer_b/maybe-even-deeper-layer/conv2d_1 (None, ...)
... etc ...
```

In Tensorflow v.0 or v.1, I would do something like:

```
for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
    print(n.name, n.shape)
```

Is there a way to prints more details when I have a keras model?

Comment: I only know you can make the `LayerA` and `LayerB` instead a submodel then you can use like `model_func.get_layer('layer_a').summary()` but probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The summary will not do this automatically, so you have to adapt. You can, for instance, create a recurrent summary:

```
def full_summary(layer):

    #check if this layer has layers
    if hasattr(layer, 'layers'):
        print('summary for ' + layer.name)
        layer.summary()
        print('\n\n')

        for l in layer.layers:
            full_summary(l)
```

Use it as:

```
full_summary(my_model)
```

Comment: Is there `.summary()` method for a keras layer?

Comment: Not sure, but you can always transform those custom layers into `Model` instead. Every `Model` is a `Layer`.